# i want this output using recursive function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to write the best javascript function for getting this output.
`['1','p1','p11','2','p2','p21']` for this input.

```
const arr = [{

        "children": [{
            "property1": "1",

            "children": [{
                "property1": "p1",

                "children": [{
                    "property1": "p11",

                    "children": [

                    ]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {

        "children": [{
            "property1": "2",

            "children": [{
                "property1": "p2",

                "children": [{
                    "property1": "p21",

                    "children": [

                    ]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

How to get the output using recursive function. It is loop of children. if the children length is 0 then don't add otherwise add arrays of property1.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Yes, using a recursive function with a loop of the children sounds like a good solution. Use that approach! If you need help with your implementation, please show us your attempt.

Comment: See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple recursive function for this.

- First  check whether the current Array element or child contains `property1` or not. if it is present simply push `property1` to the result array.
- Then you need to check whether the child has its own child(or subchilds) if it has its own children than recursively call the `getProperty()` method passing the child array as the new parameter to the function along with the result array.

```js
const arr = [{ "children": [{ "property1": "1", "children": [{ "property1": "p1", "children": [{ "property1": "p11", "children": [ ] }] }] }] }, { "children": [{ "property1": "2", "children": [{ "property1": "p2", "children": [{ "property1": "p21", "children": [ ] }] }] }] } ];

function getProperty(arr, result){
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].property1)
      result.push(arr[i].property1);
    if(arr[i].children && arr[i].children.length)
      getProperty(arr[i].children, result);
  }
}
let result = [];
getProperty(arr,result)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: it worked but is this the right way to do this?